# Delete_Click event with Multiple Gridviews within Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a page with an UpdatePanel and 5 GridViews. I have a delete button outside of the Gridview to allow for multiple files to be deleted quickly. Is it possible to use the one delete button click event for all of the Gridviews?

```
  Protected Sub deletePacketBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles deletePacketBtn.Click
    'Loop through all the rows in gridview
    For Each gvrow As C1GridViewRow In packetGrid.Rows
        'Finiding checkbox control in gridview for particular row
        Dim chkdelete As CheckBox = CType(gvrow.FindControl("chkDelete"), CheckBox)
        'Condition to check checkbox selected or not
        If chkdelete.Checked Then
            'Getting ID of particular row using datakey value
            Dim fileID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(packetGrid.DataKeys(gvrow.RowIndex).Value)
            PacketDataSource.DeleteParameters("original_PKT_Key").DefaultValue = fileID.ToString
            PacketDataSource.Delete()

        End If
    Next
    packetGrid.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Yes, `sender` is the `GridView` that caused the Delete event to be raised.</strike>

If you just cast `sender` as a GridView (don't know the correct VB syntax, sorry), you'll know which one caused the event.

The following code above is only applicable for the Delete event of GridView, not a button-click.

Comment: What about the DataSources being specific to an individual grid. How would I approach that and Parameter 'KEY' being different?

Comment: If everything is different, you'll end up having so much conditional logic in your one `Delete` handler, that you'd be more concise and less confusing to just have 5 separate `Delete` handlers for each of the grids.

Comment: I just tried casting the GridView as Sender and I get the error "Unable to cast type ....button to ....GridView."  I wanted to avoid having multiple buttons for the Delete Method, and not having to hide them pending which grid is visible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question and thought you were using the Delete functionality INSIDE the GridView.  Now I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: The approach I've taken is having 5 Delete handlers and adding them to the Delete Button click in the Code-behind. Thanks all.